# Change GMLib default marker

Tags: delphi, icons, gmlib

I am using gmlib in a delphi application and it's living up to my needs.  I load markers form a table of  coordinates, but now I want to replace the default marker style.  Since I am doing this all in code, I don't have any gmmarker items.  My code is looped simply:

```
gmmarker1.Add(qryPoints.FieldByName('lat').AsFloat,qryPoints.FieldByName('lon').AsFloat,address);
```

when I try to change the icon using:

```
gmmarker1.Items[0].Icon:='c:\measle.png';
```

I get an error 'Argument out of range'

Is it possible to change the default icon without adding an item to the marker?  Or am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Add method of TGMMarker returns a TMarker object. You can use it to assign more properties like Icon property. However, gmmarker1.Items[0].Icon or gmmarker1[0].Icon must be work if exists any marker. Check gmmarker1.Count before

Comment: That did it, thank you.  I added a variable, markers (int) and added the code: markers:=gmmarker1.Count;
  for markers := 0 to markers -1 do
    begin
      gmmarker1.Items[markers].Icon:='c:\fdms\measle.png';
    end;